# GemFire object serialization using Java Serialization

Tags: spring-session, gemfire, spring-data-gemfire

We are using *Spring Session* management with GemFire for Session handling.

Currently we are upgraded the GemFire version to the `2.1.2` release.  We have used *Delta Serialization* for `Session` object. We have a huge Session object and it has dependent objects within the Session object. We have used *Java Serialization* in old GemFire version `2.0.5`.

Can I use *Java Serialization* for object inside the Session in `2.1.2` version?

We are using...

```
sessionSerializerBeanName = 
    GemFireHttpSessionConfiguration.SESSION_DATA_SERIALIZER_BEAN_NAME
```

... for serializing `Session` object.

When using this approach, we have to load all the application JARs to GemFire cache server.

Which annotation or attribute needs to be used for serializing objects inside the `Session` object using *Java Serialization*?

We are doing this with container deployment where one complete transaction will be processed by multiple containers.

Answer (score 0):

First, the versions of GemFire to which you refer are Spring Session for Pivotal GemFire versions (e.g. *Spring Session Data GemFire* (SSDG) `2.1.2.RELEASE`; see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/releases)).

FYI, to determine the actual version of Pivotal GemFire, you must follow the transitive dependencies.  For instance, SSDG `2.1.2.RELEASE` [depends on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/blob/2.1.2.RELEASE/gradle.properties#L13) Spring Data for Pivotal GemFire (SDG) `Lovelace` / `2.1.3.RELEASE`.  SDG `2.1.x` in turn [depends on](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-data-gemfire/blob/2.1.3.RELEASE/pom.xml#L25) **Pivotal GemFire** `9.5.2`.  `9.5.2` is the Pivotal GemFire version in use here.

Regarding...

> *Can I use Java Serialization for object inside the Session in 2.1.2 version?*

Yes!

In general, if your application domain objects (e.g. `Customer`), stored in the (HTTP) `Session` as a `Session` **attribute value** 1) is `java.io.Serializable`, 2) there does **NOT** exist a "registered" [`PdxSerializer`](http://gemfire-95-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/pdx/PdxSerializer.html) or [`DataSerializer`](http://gemfire-95-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/DataSerializer.html) capable of de/serializing your application domain objects 3) nor does any of your application domain objects (e.g. `Customer`) implement [`DataSerializble`](http://gemfire-95-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/DataSerializable.html) or [`PdxSerializable`](http://gemfire-95-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/pdx/PdxSerializable.html), then your objects must be serializable using *Java Serialization* and therefore, will be serialized using *Java Serialization*, or a Serialization Exception will occur.  This is particularly true anytime GemFire sends data between client and server, between peer members in a cluster (i.e. distributed system), over a WAN topology, or anytime GemFire overflows/persists data to disk.  If GemFire's own [Serialization frameworks](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/97/geode/developing/data_serialization/data_serialization_options.html) and mechanics are not used, then *Java Serialization* (if allowed) is the fallback serialization strategy applied.

SSDG is careful when de/serializing the `Session` object and it contents to delegate back to GemFire to apply serialization logic to the contents of (application domain objects stored in) the `Session` as well, especially when GemFire's [*Data Serialization* framework](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/97/geode/developing/data_serialization/gemfire_data_serialization.html) is used to de/serialize the `Session` object itself, which in your case, it is since you have configured...

```
sessionSerializerBeanName = 
    GemFireHttpSessionConfiguration.SESSION_DATA_SERIALIZER_BEAN_NAME
```

Technically, you can see this delegation, starting with the `Session` object ([here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/blob/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-session-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/gemfire/serialization/data/provider/DataSerializableSessionSerializer.java#L115)), which is writing the `Session` attributes (key/values), which will delegate to the "registered", and provided by SSDG, `DataSerializationSessionAttributesSerializer` class, which will serialize the `Session` attribute values by delegate back to GemFire, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/blob/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-session-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/gemfire/serialization/data/provider/DataSerializableSessionAttributesSerializer.java#L98).

The SSDG `serializeObject(:Object)` helper method in turn just delegates to GemFire's [`DataSerializable.writeObject(:Object, :DataOutput, allowJavaSerialization:boolean)`](http://gemfire-95-javadocs.docs.pivotal.io/org/apache/geode/DataSerializer.html#writeObject-java.lang.Object-java.io.DataOutput-boolean-) method, [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/blob/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-session-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/gemfire/serialization/data/AbstractDataSerializableSessionSerializer.java#L102).  `allowJavaSerialization` is **true** by default, see [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/blob/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-session-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/gemfire/serialization/data/AbstractDataSerializableSessionSerializer.java#L80-L82), then [here](https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-session-data-geode/blob/2.1.2.RELEASE/spring-session-data-geode/src/main/java/org/springframework/session/data/gemfire/serialization/data/AbstractDataSerializableSessionSerializer.java#L51)).

At this point, it is all in Pivotal GemFire's hands (after the delegation by SSDG).  In general, Pivotal GemFire uses the following algorithm to apply de/serialization to any object:

1) PDX Serialization
2) Data Serialization
3) Java Serialization

Following the rules I outlined above.  You can see this logic carried out in the `InternalDataSerializer` class used by GemFire, [here](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.6.0/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/internal/InternalDataSerializer.java#L2188-L2262).  Ultimately, Java Serialization happens [here](https://github.com/apache/geode/blob/rel/v1.6.0/geode-core/src/main/java/org/apache/geode/internal/InternalDataSerializer.java#L2254-L2260), iff allowed.

Regarding...

> *Which annotation or attribute needs to be used for serializing objects inside the Session object using Java Serialization?*

There are no Annotations and/or attributes to apply *Java Serialization*; it is the default/fallback serialization strategy used when no other option has been explicitly configured.

This mean you definitely do **not** want to use SDG's [`@EnablePdx`](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/geode/docs/current/api/org/springframework/data/gemfire/config/annotation/EnablePdx.html) annotation since SDG makes it very easy to 1) identify the types eligible for de/serialization with PDX and 2) to de/serialize those objects in a stream of PDX bytes.  More details can be found in the ref docs about PDX [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#bootstrap-annotation-config-pdx) along with details about SDG's `MappingPdxSerializer` (which `@EnablePdx` applies under-the-hood, as the configured/registered `PdxSerializer` used by GemFire), [here](https://docs.spring.io/spring-data/gemfire/docs/current/reference/html/#mapping.pdx-serializer).

Also, remember to review Pivotal GemFire [documentation](http://gemfire.docs.pivotal.io/97/geode/developing/data_serialization/data_serialization_options.html) on Data Serialization, and how it works.

Hope this helps!